# What is the best practice of using make with Verilog simulators and VPI code

Tags: makefile, verilog

I have go to some reasonable stage with my first VPI project, which is intended
to aid digital filter design. At the moment I was working with Icarus, though
I'd like to test Verilator too and other simulator as some point.

So far I have this [makefile](https://github.com/errordeveloper/sftb/commit/3b1007479fa0a04b80b0b9be6bbe6985072259b0), though this is intended to build the C code and
one simple testbench. I'd like to be able to include a makefile and build/simulate
different new Verilog projects.

I haven't found much example of Makefiles for HDL projects on the net.
I'm quite happy with my implementation to some extend and can carry-on
rolling my own, though would like to see any well organised larger scale
projects. I have't yet looked at the Makefiles in OpenRISC ...

An example that I'm really looking for is of VPI testbench project, e.g. you
have done your VPI code and now want to build a small ecosystem around it
using a hierarchy of Makefiles.

Let's say, we are taking just two simulators - Icarus and Verilator.

Comment: Check out the "boldport flow" FPGA build Makefile generator... may be useful to you http://www.boldport.com

Comment: @saar interesting. Great effort! I see, that it's your project ;) Is it supposed to be web-only? I'd be very happy to see this in a form of Tk or QT app .. or even ncurses/dialog (for console freaks)! Let me know, atm I'm up for various projects :)~

Comment: Yeah, it's mine; didn't mean to hide that, and should have mentioned. Taking this discussion "off-line".

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a vary basic makefile. In our makefiles we have usually far more targets which also include the synthesis, par and simulation. Sadly they contain very vendor specific (Xilinx & Synopsys) stuff, which make it not very generic. Also we usually have a hierarchy of makefiles. We have a general, some module specifics, and also some subprojects (e.g. the memorysystem) specific.

But in case you are interrested I post one here, to give you an impression how one could look like:

```
.PHONY: default
default: rtlsim

.PHONY: help
help:
    @echo "Syntax:"
    @echo "-------"
    @echo "make [make_target] [options]"
    @echo ""
    @echo "Arguments:"
    @echo "----------"
    @echo "make_target = [bits], timing, rtlsim, rtlsimgui, laysim, laysimgui"
    @echo "  bits:       Generate bitstream (includes P&R)"
    @echo "  timing:     Generate timing report using timing analyzer (includes P&R)"
    @echo "  rtlsim:     VCS RTL simulation (text mode)"
    @echo "  rtlsimgui:  VCS RTL simulation (interactive gui mode)"
    @echo "  laysim:     VCS post-place-and-route simulation (text mode)"
    @echo "  laysimgui:  VCS post-place-and-route simulation (interactive gui mode)"
    @echo ""
    @echo "Options:"
    @echo "----------"
    @echo "target = [ml507], ml310"
    @echo "  ml507: Use Virtex-5 xc5vfx70t-1 as target FPGA (Xilinx ML507)"
    @echo "  ml310: Use Virtex-II Pro xc2vp30-6 as target FPGA (Xilinx ML310)"
    @echo "disregard_cache_stalls = [0], 1"
    @echo "  0: for normal simulation"
    @echo "  1: to disregard cache stalls (results may then be incorrect, but the simulation time without cache stalls is obtained)"
    @echo "physical_synthesis = [0], 1"
    @echo "  0: run Synplify without physical synthesis"
    @echo "  1: run Synplify with physical synthesis"
    @echo "BATCH_GUI = [default], GUI"
    @echo "  default: run Synplify in batch mode"
    @echo "  GUI:     start Synplify GUI instead"
    @echo "toplevel = [fpga], datapath, sequencer, hw_kernel, user, plb_marc, mci_marc"
    @echo "  Sets the toplevel file in the HW design hierarchy; relevant for area / timing reports"
    @echo "marc = [1], 2"
    @echo "  Chooses between usage of MARC1 and MARC2 (use the latter for 256 bit LPU transfers)"

# defaults
ifndef target
  target=ml507
endif
ifndef toplevel
  toplevel=fpga
endif
ifndef disregard_cache_stalls
  disregard_cache_stalls=0
endif
ifndef marc
  marc=1
endif

ifeq "$(target)" "ml507"
  TECHNOLOGY_NAME=VIRTEX5
  TECHNOLOGY_PART=XC5VFX70T
  TECHNOLOGY_PACKAGE=FF1136
  TECHNOLOGY_SPEED_GRADE=-1
  FREQUENCY=100.000
else
  TECHNOLOGY_NAME=VIRTEX2P
  TECHNOLOGY_PART=XC2VP30
  TECHNOLOGY_PACKAGE=FF896
  TECHNOLOGY_SPEED_GRADE=-6
  FREQUENCY=100.000
endif

ifndef physical_synthesis
  physical_synthesis=0
endif

ifndef BATCH_GUI
  BATCH_GUI=default
endif

ifeq "$(BATCH_GUI)" "default"
  BATCH_TCL=batch
else
  BATCH_TCL=tcl
endif

ifdef area_timing_result_file
  AREA_TIMING_RESULT_FILE=$(area_timing_result_file)
else
  AREA_TIMING_RESULT_FILE=area_timing_results.$(target).$(toplevel).txt
endif

ifeq ($(disregard_cache_stalls),1)
  DISREGARD_CACHE_STALLS=+define+DISREGARD_CACHE_STALLS
else
  DISREGARD_CACHE_STALLS=
endif

# base directory for MARC, SimEnv, AddOns, etc.
ifeq "$(target)" "ml507"
  PRAKTIKUM_BASE=$(COMRADE_ROOT_DIR)/COMRADE/sim_synth/v5
else
  PRAKTIKUM_BASE=$(COMRADE_ROOT_DIR)/COMRADE/sim_synth/v2p
endif

BRAM_VERILOG=$(COMRADE_ROOT_DIR)/COMRADE/sim_synth/platform_independent/bram

# command to get the directory of the current test example,
# relative to Comrade's "tests" directory
TEST_EXAMPLE=$(shell pwd | sed 's/.*tests\///g' | sed 's/\/sim_env_acem3//g')

# name of target RC executable
PROG=main

# Modlib path
MODLIB=$(COMRADE_ROOT_DIR)/modlib

# path to the instantiated verilog modules
MODULES=..

# path to the instantiated verilog blackboxes
BLACKBOXES=../blackboxes

ifeq "$(target)" "ml507"
DESIGN=user.v mci_marc.tcl
else
DESIGN=user.v plb_marc.tcl
endif

# base name of synthesis-related files
ifeq "$(target)" "ml507"
NETLIST=mci_marc
else
NETLIST=plb_marc
endif

# base name of toplevel after synthesis
TOPLEVEL=system

# current directory (which is in some cases != $(PWD)...)
CURRENT_DIR=$(shell pwd)

# "HOME" on local /scratch
SCRHOME=/scratch/$(USER)/private/tmp/$(TEST_EXAMPLE)

# directory containing MARC
ifeq ($(marc),2)
MARC=$(PRAKTIKUM_BASE)/MARC_marc2
else
MARC=$(PRAKTIKUM_BASE)/MARC
endif

# directory containing the simulation environment
ifeq ($(marc),2)
SIMENV=$(PRAKTIKUM_BASE)/SimEnv_marc2
else
SIMENV=$(PRAKTIKUM_BASE)/SimEnv
endif

# directory containing additional files (IP cores, SW, ...)
ifeq ($(marc),2)
ADDONS=$(PRAKTIKUM_BASE)/AddOns_marc2
else
ADDONS=$(PRAKTIKUM_BASE)/AddOns
endif

# ML310 Linux kernel image
VMLINUX=$(ADDONS)/zImage.elf

# TTY for serial console
CONSOLETTY=/dev/ttyS0

# path to xilinx's simulation primitives
SIMPRIMS=$(XILINX)/verilog/src/simprims
UNISIMS=$(XILINX)/verilog/src/unisims

# RC definitions
ifeq "$(target)" "ml507"
  DEVICE=xc5vfx70t
  PARTTYPE=$(DEVICE)-ff1136-1
  DEVDES=$(TOPLEVEL)-$(DEVICE)
else
  DEVICE=xc2vp30
  PARTTYPE=$(DEVICE)-ff896-6
  DEVDES=$(TOPLEVEL)-$(DEVICE)
endif


# this is the name of synplify target subdirectory
IMPL=Simple.$(target).fpga

# configuration files for $(VIRSIM)
CFGRTL=default-rtl
VPDRTL=$(SCRHOME)/vcdplus-rtl-$(notdir $(PWD))
CFGLAY=default-lay
VPDLAY=$(SCRHOME)/vcdplus-lay-$(notdir $(PWD))
CFGSYN=default-syn
VPDSYN=$(SCRHOME)/vcdplus-syn-$(notdir $(PWD))
MDIRRTL=csrc.rtl
MDIRLAY=csrc.lay
MDIRSYN=csrc.syn

# path to the cross OS installation directory
#CROSS=/acs/ace/rtems
#CROSS=/images/ml310/ml310_rootfs_gentoo
CROSS=/cad/tools/acs-prak/ACS07/Cross
#CROSSBIN=$(CROSS)/bin
CROSSBIN=/cad/tools/crosscompiler/powerpc-405-linux/bin

# the RTEMS/ACE2 IO server
SERVER=$(CROSSBIN)/rtemsserver -l

# the compile-flow tools
#CC=$(CROSSBIN)/sparc-rtems-gcc
CC=$(CROSSBIN)/powerpc-405-linux-gnu-gcc
#LD=$(CROSSBIN)/sparc-rtems-gcc
LD=$(CROSSBIN)/powerpc-405-linux-gnu-gcc
COPY=$(CROSSBIN)/sparc-rtems-objcopy
BIT2O=$(CROSSBIN)/bit2o
VPP=vpp
SED=sed
XC=xc
ifeq ($(SYNPLIFY_VERSION),8.8)
SYNPLIFY=synplify_pro
else
SYNPLIFY=synplify_premier_dp
endif
NGDBUILD=ngdbuild
MAP=map
PAR=par
NETGEN=netgen
BITGEN=bitgen
TRCE=trce
IMPACT=impact
XMD=xmd
VCS=vcs
SIMVRTL=simv.rtl
SIMVLAY=simv.lay
SIMVSYN=simv.syn
VIRSIM=virsim
XPOWER=xpwr

# the compile options

#CCOPTS=-fasm -specs bsp_specs -qrtems -O3 -I include -I $(CROSS)/sparc-rtems/include/rtems-ace2
CCOPTS=-O3 -I $(CROSS)/usr/include
#LDOPTS=-fasm -specs bsp_specs -qrtems -O3
LDOPTS=-O3
COPYOPTS=-O binary
SYNPLIFYOPTS=$(filter %.tcl,$(DESIGN))
NGDBUILDOPTS=-uc $(ADDONS)/$(TOPLEVEL).ucf -sd $(ADDONS) -sd $(MODLIB) -sd $(MODLIB)/$(target)
MAPOPTS=-pr b -detail -timing -ol high -xe c -w
PAROPTS=-ol high -xe c -w
BITGENOPTS=
TRCEOPTS=-v 10
TRCEOPTS_HG=-v 10 -u 10
VCSOPTS=+v2k +notimingchecks -y . -y .. -y $(MARC) +incdir+$(MARC) -y $(SIMENV) +incdir+$(SIMENV) -y $(ADDONS) +incdir+$(ADDONS) -y $(MODLIB) +incdir+$(MODLIB) -y $(BRAM_VERILOG) +incdir+$(BRAM_VERILOG) $(DISREGARD_CACHE_STALLS)

# Don't change these

ifeq ($(target),ml507)
  ifeq ($(disregard_cache_stalls),1)
    VCSRTLOPTS=+define+TESTBENCH=testbench_rtl -v ../simdefs.v -v $(UNISIMS)/../glbl.v $(VCSOPTS) -y $(UNISIMS) -y $(SIMPRIMS) +libext+.v $(SIMENV)/testbench_rtl.v
  else
    VCSRTLOPTS=+define+TESTBENCH=testbench_rtl -v ../simdefs.v -v marc.v -v $(SIMENV)/ppc440.v -v $(SIMENV)/temac.v -v $(UNISIMS)/../glbl.v $(VCSOPTS) -y $(UNISIMS) -y $(SIMPRIMS) +libext+.v $(SIMENV)/testbench_rtl.v
  endif
  VCSSYNOPTS=+define+TESTBENCH=testbench_syn -v ../simdefs.v -v $(SIMENV)/ppc440.v -v $(SIMENV)/temac.v -v $(IMPL)/$(NETLIST).vm -v $(UNISIMS)/../glbl.v $(VCSOPTS) -y $(UNISIMS) -y $(SIMPRIMS) +libext+.v $(SIMENV)/testbench_syn.v
  VCSLAYOPTS=+define+TESTBENCH=testbench_lay -v ../simdefs.v -v $(SIMENV)/ppc440.v -v $(IMPL)/$(DEVDES).v -v $(SIMPRIMS)/../glbl.v $(VCSOPTS) -y $(SIMPRIMS) +libext+.v $(SIMENV)/testbench_lay.v
else
  ifeq ($(disregard_cache_stalls),1)
    VCSRTLOPTS=+define+TESTBENCH=testbench_rtl -v ../simdefs.v -v $(UNISIMS)/../glbl.v $(VCSOPTS) -y $(UNISIMS) -y $(SIMPRIMS) +libext+.v $(SIMENV)/testbench_rtl.v
  else
    VCSRTLOPTS=+define+TESTBENCH=testbench_rtl -v ../simdefs.v -v marc.v -v $(SIMENV)/ppc405.v -v $(UNISIMS)/../glbl.v $(VCSOPTS) -y $(UNISIMS) -y $(SIMPRIMS) +libext+.v $(SIMENV)/testbench_rtl.v
  endif
  VCSSYNOPTS=+define+TESTBENCH=testbench_syn -v ../simdefs.v -v $(SIMENV)/ppc405.v -v $(IMPL)/$(NETLIST).vm -v $(UNISIMS)/../glbl.v $(VCSOPTS) -y $(UNISIMS) -y $(SIMPRIMS) +libext+.v $(SIMENV)/testbench_syn.v
  VCSLAYOPTS=+define+TESTBENCH=testbench_lay -v ../simdefs.v -v $(SIMENV)/ppc405.v -v $(IMPL)/$(DEVDES).v -v $(SIMPRIMS)/../glbl.v $(VCSOPTS) -y $(SIMPRIMS) +libext+.v $(SIMENV)/testbench_lay.v
endif

# make rules

default: all

.c.o:
        $(CC) -c $(CCOPTS) $<

$(PROG).exe:  $(PROG).o $(DEVDES).o
        $(LD) -o $(PROG).exe $(PROG).o  $(DEVDES).o $(LDOPTS) $(CROSS)/sparc-rtems/lib/libacevapi.a -lm
$(PROG).bin: $(PROG).exe
        $(COPY) $(COPYOPTS) $(PROG).exe $(PROG).bin

$(PROG): $(PROG).o
        $(LD) -o $(PROG) $(PROG).o $(LDOPTS) $(CROSS)/usr/lib/libadmxrc2.so.2


# build hardware objects

#$(SIMENV)/%.v: $(ADDONS)/%.ngc
#       $(NETGEN) -w -sim -ofmt verilog $< $@
#       rm $(basename $@).nlf

$(DEVDES).o: $(IMPL)/$(DEVDES).o
        cp $(IMPL)/$(DEVDES).o .

$(IMPL)/$(DEVDES).o: $(IMPL)/$(DEVDES).bit
        cd $(IMPL); \
        $(BIT2O) $(DEVDES).bit $(DEVDES).o config_$(TOPLEVEL) ;\
        cd ..

$(VPDRTL).vpd: $(MARC)/*.v marc.v $(SIMENV)/*.v $(patsubst $(ADDONS)/%.ngc,$(SIMENV)/%.v,$(wildcard $(ADDONS)/*.ngc)) $(filter %.v,$(DESIGN))
        mkdir -p -m 700 $(dir $(VPDRTL))
        $(VCS) -line -PP +define+BATCH -Mupdate -Mdir=$(MDIRRTL) -o $(SIMVRTL) $(VCSRTLOPTS)
        ./$(SIMVRTL) +vpddrivers +vpdfile+$(VPDRTL).vpd

$(VPDLAY).vpd: $(SIMENV)/*.v $(IMPL)/$(DEVDES).v
        mkdir -p -m 700 $(dir $(VPDLAY))
        $(VCS) -line -PP +define+BATCH -Mupdate -Mdir=$(MDIRLAY) -o $(SIMVLAY) $(VCSLAYOPTS)
        ./$(SIMVLAY) +vpddrivers +vpdfile+$(VPDLAY).vpd

$(VPDSYN).vpd: $(SIMENV)/*.v $(patsubst $(ADDONS)/%.ngc,$(SIMENV)/%.v,$(wildcard $(ADDONS)/*.ngc)) $(IMPL)/$(NETLIST).vm
        mkdir -p -m 700 $(dir $(VPDSYN))
        $(VCS) -line -PP +define+BATCH -Mupdate -Mdir=$(MDIRSYN) -o $(SIMVSYN) $(VCSSYNOPTS)
        ./$(SIMVSYN) +vpddrivers +vpdfile+$(VPDSYN).vpd

$(IMPL)/$(DEVDES).v: $(IMPL)/$(DEVDES).ncd
        cd $(IMPL); \
        $(NETGEN) -w -sim -ofmt verilog -sdf_path ../$(IMPL)/$(DEVDES).sdf $(DEVDES) -pcf $(DEVDES).pcf; \
        $(SED) -i -e 's/SIM_COLLISION_CHECK = "ALL"/SIM_COLLISION_CHECK = "GENERATE_X_ONLY"/g' $(DEVDES).v ;\
        cd ..

$(IMPL)/$(DEVDES).hg.twr: $(IMPL)/$(DEVDES).ncd
        cd $(IMPL); \
        $(TRCE) $(TRCEOPTS_HG) $(DEVDES).ncd ;\
        mv $(DEVDES).twr $(DEVDES).hg.twr
        cd ..

$(IMPL)/$(DEVDES).twr: $(IMPL)/$(DEVDES).ncd
        cd $(IMPL); \
        $(TRCE) $(TRCEOPTS) $(DEVDES).ncd ;\
        cd ..

$(IMPL)/$(DEVDES).bit: $(IMPL)/$(DEVDES).ncd
        cd $(IMPL); \
        $(BITGEN) -w $(BITGENOPTS) $(DEVDES) $(DEVDES);\
        cd ..

$(IMPL)/$(DEVDES).ncd: $(IMPL)/$(DEVDES)_map.ncd
        cd $(IMPL); \
        $(PAR) $(PAROPTS) $(DEVDES)_map.ncd $(DEVDES).ncd $(DEVDES).pcf ;\
        cd ..

$(IMPL)/$(DEVDES)_map.ncd: $(IMPL)/$(DEVDES).ngd
        cd $(IMPL); \
        XIL_TIMING_ALLOW_IMPOSSIBLE=1 $(MAP) $(MAPOPTS) -o $(DEVDES)_map.ncd $(DEVDES).ngd $(DEVDES).pcf ; \
        cd ..

$(IMPL)/$(DEVDES).ngd: $(IMPL)/$(NETLIST).edf $(wildcard $(ADDONS)/*.ngc) $(wildcard $(ADDONS)/*.edf)
        cd $(IMPL); \
        $(NGDBUILD) $(NGDBUILDOPTS) -p $(PARTTYPE) $(TOPLEVEL) $(DEVDES).ngd; \
        cd ..

$(IMPL)/$(NETLIST).edf $(IMPL)/$(NETLIST).vm: $(MARC)/*.v marc.v $(wildcard $(ADDONS)/*.v) $(filter %.v,$(DESIGN)) $(filter %.tcl,$(DESIGN))
        DESIGN=$(CURRENT_DIR) IMPL=$(IMPL) NETLIST=$(NETLIST) MARC=$(MARC) \
        ADDONS=$(ADDONS) MODULES=$(MODULES) MODLIB=$(MODLIB) BRAM_VERILOG=$(BRAM_VERILOG) BLACKBOXES=$(BLACKBOXES) \
        TECHNOLOGY_NAME=$(TECHNOLOGY_NAME) TECHNOLOGY_PART=$(TECHNOLOGY_PART) \
        TECHNOLOGY_PACKAGE=$(TECHNOLOGY_PACKAGE) TECHNOLOGY_SPEED_GRADE=$(TECHNOLOGY_SPEED_GRADE) \
        FREQUENCY=$(FREQUENCY) PHYSICAL_SYNTHESIS=$(physical_synthesis) \
        BATCH_GUI=$(BATCH_GUI) $(SYNPLIFY) -$(BATCH_TCL) $(SYNPLIFYOPTS)

# if link_marcdefs_v_$(target)_created does not exist, the marcdefs.v link is (re-)created
link_marcdefs_v_$(target)_created:
        -rm -f link_marcdefs_v_ml310_created link_marcdefs_v_ml507_created 2>/dev/null
        @touch link_marcdefs_v_$(target)_created

marcdefs.v: marcdefs.$(target).v link_marcdefs_v_$(target)_created
        -rm -f marcdefs.v 2>/dev/null
        ln -s marcdefs.$(target).v marcdefs.v
        @touch marcdefs.v

marc.v: $(MARC)/marc.vpp marcdefs.v
        $(VPP) $(MARC)/marc.vpp > marc.v 2>/dev/null

.PHONY: all
all:    $(PROG) bits
        @echo -e "OK, ML310 Linux executable for $(PROG) built. Run it using \n\tmake linux\nand after logging in, execute \n\t$(SCRHOME)/$(PROG)"

.PHONY: rtlsimbatch
rtlsimbatch: $(VPDRTL).vpd
        $(VIRSIM) +define+RTLSIM +vpdfile+$(VPDRTL).vpd +cfgfile+$(CFGRTL).cfg $(VCSRTLOPTS)

.PHONY: rtlsimgui
ifeq ($(disregard_cache_stalls),1)
rtlsimgui: $(MARC)/*.v ../simdefs.v ../stimulus.v $(SIMENV)/*.v $(filter %.v,$(DESIGN))
        mkdir -p -m 700 $(dir $(VPDRTL))
        $(VCS) -line -RI -Mupdate -Mdir=$(MDIRRTL) -o $(SIMVRTL) +define+RTLSIM +vpdfile+$(VPDRTL).vpd +cfgfile+$(CFGRTL).cfg $(VCSRTLOPTS)
else
rtlsimgui: $(MARC)/*.v ../simdefs.v ../stimulus.v marc.v $(SIMENV)/*.v $(patsubst $(ADDONS)/%.ngc,$(SIMENV)/%.v,$(wildcard $(ADDONS)/*.ngc)) $(filter %.v,$(DESIGN))
        mkdir -p -m 700 $(dir $(VPDRTL))
        $(VCS) -line -RI -Mupdate -Mdir=$(MDIRRTL) -o $(SIMVRTL) +define+RTLSIM +vpdfile+$(VPDRTL).vpd +cfgfile+$(CFGRTL).cfg $(VCSRTLOPTS)
endif

.PHONY: rtlsim
ifeq ($(disregard_cache_stalls),1)
rtlsim: marcdefs.v ../simdefs.v ../stimulus.v $(SIMENV)/*.v $(filter %.v,$(DESIGN))
        mkdir -p -m 700 $(dir $(VPDRTL))
        $(VCS) -line -PP -Mupdate -Mdir=$(MDIRRTL) -o $(SIMVRTL) +define+RTLSIM +vpdfile+$(VPDRTL).vpd +cfgfile+$(CFGRTL).cfg $(VCSRTLOPTS)
        ./$(SIMVRTL)
else
rtlsim: $(MARC)/*.v ../simdefs.v ../stimulus.v marc.v $(SIMENV)/*.v $(patsubst $(ADDONS)/%.ngc,$(SIMENV)/%.v,$(wildcard $(ADDONS)/*.ngc)) $(filter %.v,$(DESIGN))
        mkdir -p -m 700 $(dir $(VPDRTL))
        $(VCS) -line -PP -Mupdate -Mdir=$(MDIRRTL) -o $(SIMVRTL) +define+RTLSIM +vpdfile+$(VPDRTL).vpd +cfgfile+$(CFGRTL).cfg $(VCSRTLOPTS)
        ./$(SIMVRTL)
endif

.PHONY: laysimbatch
laysimbatch: $(VPDLAY).vpd
        $(VIRSIM) +vpdfile+$(VPDLAY).vpd +cfgfile+$(CFGLAY).cfg $(VCSLAYOPTS)

.PHONY: laysimgui
laysimgui: $(SIMENV)/*.v $(IMPL)/$(DEVDES).v
        mkdir -p -m 700 $(dir $(VPDLAY))
        $(VCS) -line -RI -Mupdate -Mdir=$(MDIRLAY) -o $(SIMVLAY) +vpdfile+$(VPDLAY).vpd +cfgfile+$(CFGLAY).cfg $(VCSLAYOPTS)

.PHONY: laysim
laysim: $(SIMENV)/*.v ../simdefs.v ../stimulus.v $(IMPL)/$(DEVDES).v
        mkdir -p -m 700 $(dir $(VPDLAY))
        $(VCS) -line -PP -Mupdate -Mdir=$(MDIRLAY) -o $(SIMVLAY) +vpdfile+$(VPDLAY).vpd +cfgfile+$(CFGLAY).cfg $(VCSLAYOPTS)
        ./$(SIMVLAY)

.PHONY: synsimbatch
synsimbatch: $(VPDSYN).vpd
        $(VIRSIM) +vpdfile+$(VPDSYN).vpd +cfgfile+$(CFGSYN).cfg $(VCSSYNOPTS)

.PHONY: synsim
synsim: $(SIMENV)/*.v ../simdefs.v ../stimulus.v $(patsubst $(ADDONS)/%.ngc,$(SIMENV)/%.v,$(wildcard $(ADDONS)/*.ngc)) $(IMPL)/$(NETLIST).vm
        mkdir -p -m 700 $(dir $(VPDSYN))
        $(VCS) -line -RI -Mupdate -Mdir=$(MDIRSYN) -o $(SIMVSYN) +vpdfile+$(VPDSYN).vpd +cfgfile+$(CFGSYN).cfg $(VCSSYNOPTS)

.PHONY: timing
ifeq "$(physical_synthesis)" "1"
# Synplify creates .edf, .ncd and .twr in one call!
timing: $(IMPL)/$(NETLIST).edf
        cat $(IMPL)/par_1/$(NETLIST).twr
        $(COMRADE_ROOT_DIR)/COMRADE/scripts/XilinxReportReader/xrr $(TECHNOLOGY_NAME) \
                $(IMPL)/par_1/$(NETLIST)_map.mrp $(IMPL)/par_1/$(NETLIST).twr >$(AREA_TIMING_RESULT_FILE)
else
# Create only .edf by Synplify, rest using Makefile
timing: $(IMPL)/$(DEVDES).twr
        cat $(IMPL)/$(DEVDES).twr
        $(COMRADE_ROOT_DIR)/COMRADE/scripts/XilinxReportReader/xrr $(TECHNOLOGY_NAME) \
                $(IMPL)/$(DEVDES)_map.mrp $(IMPL)/$(DEVDES).twr >$(AREA_TIMING_RESULT_FILE)
endif

# create .vcd from .vpd for power analysis
$(VPDLAY).vcd: $(VPDLAY).vpd
        vpd2vcd $(VPDLAY).vpd $(VPDLAY).vcd

# create .xad from .vcd for power analysis
$(VPDLAY).xad: $(VPDLAY).vcd
        /cad/tools/ise-9.2/bin/lin/vcd2xad.pl -f $(VPDLAY).vcd

# create .saif from .vcd
$(VPDLAY).saif: $(VPDLAY).vcd
        vcd2saif -i $(VPDLAY).vcd -o $(VPDLAY).saif

# power analysis
.PHONY: power
power: $(IMPL)/$(DEVDES).ncd $(VPDLAY).saif
        $(XPOWER) -v -a $(IMPL)/$(DEVDES).ncd $(IMPL)/$(DEVDES).pcf -s $(VPDLAY).vcd
        @echo "Power results written to file \"$(IMPL)/$(DEVDES).pwr\"."

# area results
.PHONY: area
area: $(IMPL)/$(DEVDES)_map.ncd

.PHONY: area_all
area_all:
        # V2P
        make area_datapath toplevel=datapath
        make area_sequencer toplevel=sequencer
        make area_hw_kernel toplevel=hw_kernel
        make area_plb_marc toplevel=plb_marc
        make area
        # V5
        make area_datapath toplevel=datapath target=ml507
        make area_sequencer toplevel=sequencer target=ml507
        make area_hw_kernel toplevel=hw_kernel target=ml507

.PHONY: timing_all
timing_all:
        # V2P
        make timing_datapath toplevel=datapath
        make timing_sequencer toplevel=sequencer
        make timing_hw_kernel toplevel=hw_kernel
        make timing_plb_marc toplevel=plb_marc
        make timing
        # V5
        make timing_datapath toplevel=datapath target=ml507
        make timing_sequencer toplevel=sequencer target=ml507
        make timing_hw_kernel toplevel=hw_kernel target=ml507

.PHONY: bits
bits: $(IMPL)/$(DEVDES).bit

.PHONY: download
download: bits
        cd $(IMPL); \
        echo -e "setMode    -bscan \
               \nsetCable   -p lpt1 \
               \naddDevice  -p 1 -part xccace \
               \naddDevice  -p 2 -file $(DEVDES).bit \
               \nprogram    -p 2 \
               \nquit" > download.cmd ; \
        $(IMPACT) -batch download.cmd ; \
        cd ..

.PHONY: linux
linux: $(PROG) $(VMLINUX) download
        mkdir -p -m 700 $(SCRHOME)
        cp -a $(PROG) $(SCRHOME)
        cd $(IMPL); \
        echo -e "connect ppc hw \
               \nrst \
               \nafter 1700 set end 1 \
               \nvwait end \
               \ndow $(VMLINUX) \
               \ncon \
               \nexit" > download.tcl ; \
        echo -e "set bps 115200 \
               \nset msdos "off" \
               \nset del2bs "off" \
               \nbind_function 1 \"quitchr\" \
               \nshell \"$(XMD) -tcl download.tcl\" \
               \necho \"Linux wird auf der seriellen Konsole gestartet...\" \
               \n" > download.xc ; \
        $(XC) -l $(CONSOLETTY) -s download.xc ; \
        cd ..

.PHONY: cosim
cosim:
        make -C cosimulation/
        cosimulation/simv

.PHONY: cosim_gui
cosim_gui:
        make -C cosimulation/
        cosimulation/simv -gui

.PHONY: cosim_clean
cosim_clean:
        make clean -C cosimulation/

.PHONY: clean
clean:
        rm -f $(PROG).exe $(PROG).bin $(PROG).run $(PROG).o $(PROG) $(DEVDES).o $(VPDRTL).vpd $(VPDLAY).vpd $(VPDSYN).vpd $(SIMVRTL) $(SIMVLAY) $(SIMVSYN) marc.v stdout.log vcs.key
        rm -rf Simple.ml310.* Simple.ml507.* $(IMPL) $(IMPL).datapath $(IMPL).sequencer $(IMPL).user $(IMPL).plb_marc
        rm -rf $(SIMVRTL).daidir $(SIMVLAY).daidir $(SIMVSYN).daidir $(MDIRRTL) $(MDIRLAY) $(MDIRSYN)

# Switch between different top-level modules
ifeq "$(toplevel)" "datapath"
  include Makefile.datapath
endif
ifeq "$(toplevel)" "sequencer"
  include Makefile.sequencer
endif
ifeq "$(toplevel)" "hw_kernel"
  include Makefile.hw_kernel
endif
ifeq "$(toplevel)" "user"
  include Makefile.user
endif
ifeq "$(toplevel)" "plb_marc"
  include Makefile.plb_marc
endif
ifeq "$(toplevel)" "mci_marc"
  include Makefile.mci_marc
endif
```

Comment: this is a good answer, though what I'm looking at is just simulation for DPS algorithms. I got a bit of VPI code and it can only be used for testbenches. Well... I'll probably come-up with a solution eventually...